# failed to execute goal org apache maven plugins maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: testng, maven-surefire-plugin

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Doy6u.png)

[POM.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auc7z.png)

I am using Java 11 and 3.0.0-M4 maven surefire plugin

Answer (score 0):

Here java class created src/main/java it should be created in src/tests/java.